# How to run a background process using Worklight?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Can you please guide me how to run a background process/service while using Worklight in Android? I have looked at many places but found nothing helpful regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're asking about running a background process when the app is in the background. The problem is that JavaScript in PhoneGap does not run when the app is in the background. To provide background process capability you'll need to create a plugin to manage the background process.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

There used to be some documentation from Worklight about creating PhoneGap plugins to be used in Worklight apps but I can't seem to find it.

There is already an existing plugin to help manage background processes in Android

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService

Comment: thank you for the link. i was actually working on something else and came accross plugins for phonegap and was able to implement it in worklight app. it was Notification Plugin for phonegap

Comment: Is there a way to call a worklight adapter from the native process ? Or the request has to come only  by javascript?

Comment: @HoucemBerrayana You can make an HTTP request directly to the Worklight server to invoke an adapter. The Worklight JS API provides a wrapper around making that AJAX call. Once you know the URL and payload structure you can have any client (native or JS) make the same requests.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it sounds like the flow you describe requires running a plugin from the javascript code, and starting a service from within the plugin.
The async issues here could be a bit tricky - as the return "from" the plugin to the js is async, but also the thread itself (service) inside the native code.
So wouldn't it be enough to run your native code synchronously ? (this would be synchronous "relative" to the native but async "relative" to the js)

android service - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about JavaScript part of the application you can detach a thread using setTimeout(function(){...}, 0);. Thats the closest thing to background thread JavaScript have to provide. You can, of course, look into web workers, but that will make things a bit more complex.

Comment: that was good idea. but i was rather looking for what we call service in Android. a process that keeps running in background even when app is not active